# Can Cassandra support multi-DC cluster with different number of nodes?

Tags: cassandra

I want to be able to get the backup/replicarw of operational data to a single node so we can do some adhoc queries.

Having just one machine handle this replica will be work for now.

Is this possible ? If not what are the arguments against it ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can have different number of nodes in each data center. Set the replication factor as per your requirement.

E.g. If you have DC1 with 4 nodes and going to add DC2 with 1 node then replication factor for your keyspace should be `DC1=x,DC2=1`(where x<=4).

To add one more data center you need to check the Topology, Snitch and seeds configurations. 
E.g. If you are using SimpleSnitch then you can't have multiple data centers, So you need to change your snitch and topology. Check this [link](http://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_switch_snitch.html) which explains more about changing snitch and topology.